# CloudFormation: EC2 is not finding VPC and is not launching

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am trying to do launch ec2 in VPC but it is not detecting VPC and not launching also suggesting to check Documentation.

Could you please check below code it looks some security group issue

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
# vpc creation

    VPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
        EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
        EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
        InstanceTenancy: dedicated
        Tags:
        - Key: test
          Value: test1

    #internet gateway creation      

    InternetGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway      

    VPCGatewayAttachment:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway      

    SubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/20
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

    SubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        CidrBlock: 10.0.16.0/20
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

    SubnetC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        CidrBlock: 10.0.32.0/20
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

    RouteTable:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VPC

    InternetRoute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      DependsOn: InternetGateway
      Properties:
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

    SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA

    SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB

    SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC              

    AppNode:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
      Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        ImageId: ami-c29e1cb8
        KeyName: test_devops_east_1
        AvailabilityZone: us-east-1c
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref AppNodeSG 
        SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC    

    AppNodeSG:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: Test Ec2 ssh and VPC
        VpcId: !Ref VPC 
        SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
```

Run from:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test --template-body file://~/Downloads/CFT/stack.yml --profile devops --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is here:

```
    InstanceTenancy: dedicated
```

The VPC has been configured to only permit instances launched with Dedicated tenancy.

However, `t2.micro` is not available for dedicated tenancy, therefore the configuration fails.

This resulted in the error:

> The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

Either remove the `InstanceTenancy` requirement or choose an [instance type that is supported by dedicated tenancy](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/dedicated-instances/).

Comment: Thank you , I got what you said thank you for support